# Update column based on grouped date values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Edited/reposted with correct sample output.

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
  "Year": [2021, 2021, 2023, 2015, 2017, 2018],
  "Combined": ['started', 'finished', 'started', 'started', 'finished', 'started'],
  "bool": [True, False, False, True, False, False],
"Update": ['started', 'finished', 'started', 'started', 'finished', 'started']

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df) 

ID  Year  Combined   bool  
1  2021   started   True   
1  2021  finished  False  
1  2023   started  False   
2  2015   started   True   
2  2017  finished  False  
2  2018   started  False
```

This dataframe is split into groups by `ID`.

I would like to make an updated `combined` column based on if `df['bool'] == True`, but only if `df['bool'] == True` AND there is another 'finished' row in the same group with a LATER (not the same) year.

Sample output:

```
ID  Year  Combined   bool    Update
1  2021   started   True   started
1  2021  finished  False  finished
1  2023   started  False   started
2  2015   started   True   finished
2  2017  finished  False  finished
2  2018   started  False   started
```

We are not updating the first group because there is not a `finished` value in a LATER year, and we are updating the second group because there is a `finished` value in a later year. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses temporary columns, and avoids the apply path which can be generally slow:

```py
# identify the start rows that have a True value
start_true = df.Combined.eq('started') & df['bool']

# identify rows where Combined is finished
condition = df.Combined.eq('finished')

# create more temporary variables
year_shift = df.Year.where(condition).bfill()
id_shift = df.ID.where(condition).bfill()
condition = df.ID.eq(id_shift) & df.Year.lt(year_shift)

# if it matches, 'finished', else just return what is in the Combined column
update = np.where(condition, 'finished', df.Combined)
df.assign(Update = update)

   ID  Year  Combined   bool    Update
0   1  2021   started   True   started
1   1  2021  finished  False  finished
2   1  2023   started  False   started
3   2  2015   started   True  finished
4   2  2017  finished  False  finished
5   2  2018   started  False   started
```

This solution assumes that the data is sorted on ID and Year in ascending order

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution! My example just happened to be in ascending order (by year), but the actual dataframe in question will be in descending order.

Comment: Kindly provide sample data that closely matches your actual dataframe so the solution can fit in well

Answer (score 2):

One solution I could think of is to use the `apply` and the `groupby` methods. The values of each group are passed to the `update_group` function via the `update` function. This allows performing the tests and return an updated `"Update"` column when the conditions are met. Then, the returned DataFrame is the one expected.

If I take over your example, omitting the `"Update"` column that will be created in the second part:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "Year": [2021, 2021, 2023, 2015, 2017, 2018],
    "Combined": ["started", 'finished', 'started', 'started', 'finished', 'started'],
    "bool": [True, False, False, True, False, False],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I obtain the following input DataFrame:

```
   ID  Year  Combined   bool
0   1  2021   started   True
1   1  2021  finished  False
2   1  2023   started  False
3   2  2015   started   True
4   2  2017  finished  False
5   2  2018   started  False
```

These are the two functions I use to update the DataFrame:

```py
def update_group(row, group):
    """Update each row of a group"""
    if row["bool"] is True:
        # Extract the later years entries
        group_later = group[group.Year > row.Year]

        # If finished in found, then turn the Update column to finished
        if any(group_later.Combined == "finished"):
            row["Update"] = "finished"
        else:

            row["Update"] = row["Combined"]
    else:
        row["Update"] = row["Combined"]

    return row

def update(group):
    """Apply the update to each group"""
    return group.apply(update_group, group=group, axis=1)
```

So if you apply these functions to your DataFrame:

```
df = df.groupby("ID").apply(update)
print(df)
```

the returned DataFrame is:

```
   ID  Year  Combined   bool    Update
0   1  2021   started   True   started
1   1  2021  finished  False  finished
2   1  2023   started  False   started
3   2  2015   started   True  finished
4   2  2017  finished  False  finished
5   2  2018   started  False   started
```